# How to fix the number of rows while designing pdf using iText in java

Tags: itext

I am creating one pdf file showing a list of all employees and their salaries. At the end of the page it is showing the total of all salaries.

I am using a for loop to add multiple rows to table.

The problem is:
at the end the row, the total salary doesn't fit on the same page and it is shown on the next page.

So is there any way that I can calculate the height of the page and then fix the height of each cell? And then accordingly, limit the number of rows.

So that at the end of the page, I can show the total number of rows and further record from next page.

Comment: @moskito-x Please don't clutter down people's post with incorrect formatting. Your edit should never have been approved by the robots. Don't use code formatting on things that isn't code. Don't add strange bold text and weird emphasis that the OP didn't introduce. If you decide to edit a post, then also fix fundamental grammar errors or leave it be. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the height of the page: well... you decide on the size of the page when you create a `Document` object. You can choose any size you want.

Calculate the height of a `PdfPTable`: that's explained in chapter 4 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book). When you create a `PdfPTable`, you add `PdfPCell` objects to an object that only exists in memory and that doesn't know anything about page size. By default, the width is expressed as a percentage of the available width of the page to which you'll add the `PdfPTable`. Only when you add the `PdfPTable` to a specific `Document`, the exact width and the height will be calculated (which is too late for you).

If you want to know the height in advance, you need to define an absolute width (not a percentage). Tables with the same content and a different width will have a different height. Defining an absolute width is done [like this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=80):

```
table.setTotalWidth(width);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
```

In this snippet (taken from the [TableHeight](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=80) example), `width` equals the width of the page minus the left and right margin. You're defining the width of the page and the margins upon creation of the `Document` object. By default, the page size is A4, so the default width is 595 user units and the default margins are 36 user units.

So, one way to solve your problem, would be to add rows in a loop and calculate the height of each row with the `getRowHeight()` method or the height of the complete table with the `getTotalHeight()` method (both methods will return 0 if you omit setting the total height). If you see there's not enough space to add the summary row, you can use the `deleteLastRow()` method to remove that last row and to create it anew in a new table on the next page.

That's one solution. Another solution could be to use table and cell events, but that's more difficult to explain.